# Is there any way to compare two generic objects like with JAVA Comparable?

Tags: kotlin

Is there any way to compare two objects like with JAVA **Comparable**?

```
val o1: Any
val o2: Any
```

I know they are the same class and implement JAVA **Comparable**. If I cast them to JAVA Comparable I get warning I should use Kotlin Comparable, but Kotlin version needs Type which is not known at compile time. All I need is something like this:

```
val result = (o1 as Comparable).compareTo(o2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Comparable<Any>`. It will complain of an unchecked cast, which you can suppress since you know it's safe if the types match.

```
val o1: Any = 2
val o2: Any = 4
if (o1 is Comparable<*> && o1::class == o2::class) {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    if (o1 as Comparable<Any> < o2) {
        println("it's less")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
val result = (o1 as Comparable<*>).compareTo(o2)
```

that should work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, have an error when compiling: "Out-projected type 'Comparable<*>' prohibits the use of 'public abstract operator fun compareTo(other: T): Int defined in kotlin.Comparable'"